# Is It Safe to Delete Content Types "Article" and "Basic Page"?

Tags: nodes

It is highly unlikely we will ever use these in our CMS that we're implementing.  They're just cluttering things up.  Any reason why I shouldn't delete them?

Comment: Tip for next time: If you had chosen the 'minimal' installation profile, they wouldn't have been there in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not going to use them feel free to delete them.  There will be no impact if you remove them.

Comment: You might want to also delete or edit the default frontpage view, since I think it filters by content type to display only articles.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's actually true.  It wouldn't be very logical to hard code that in since I'm sure there are plenty of people who would want to do what Jerry wants to do, and then having Drupal break on that group of people... doesn't make sense.  @Jerry, if it breaks let us know, I think you'll be fine though.

Comment: You're right, @Lester_Peabody. As long as you have content with the "promoted to front page" box checked, you'll have some content displaying on your default front page.

Comment: That's correct.